# Fix hard disk errors using Fedora live cd

Tags: linux

My hard disk is having some errors.

When it runs the pre boot scan I get:

```
Error Code 0142 Msg : Error Code 2000-0142 Msg : 
Hard Drive 0 - self test unsuccessful. 
Status : 79 

The given error code and message can be used by Technical Support to help 
diagnose the problem/ Do you want to continue testing?
```

I tried to get the command prompt so that I can use chkdsk option in windows. But the blue screen is preventing from doing that. That is why I ended up here.mins ago

I can not do anything with my laptop now. Blue screen error is preventing from doing all recovery methods from windows. So I tried using fedora live CD, and tried to do "fsck" to fix hard disc errors. But it need sudo privilege to do the same.

Is there any other alternatives by which i can fix my hard disk errors via Fedora live boot.

Comment: So why not run `fsck` with `sudo`?? Also, why are you trying to fix Windows from Linux?? Why aren't you using the Windows CD that came with your computer?

Comment: Please elaborate on *some error*. Right now this makes as much sense as "my car is doing *something* strange. How do I repair it".

Comment: Error Code 0142
Msg : Error Code 2000-0142
Msg : Hard Drive 0 - self test unsuccessful. Status : 79
The given error code and message can be used by Technical Support to help diagnose the problem/
Do yopu want to continue testing?

Above is the error i got on running a pre boot scan.
I tried to get the command prompt so that i can use chkdsk option in windows.But the blue screen is preventing from doing that.
Thats why i ended up here.

Comment: Is this an NTFS filesystem? There _is_ an `fsck.ntfs`, but it is very limited compared to the native Microsoft tools. Plus, it sounds like you may have a hardware failure far beyond the ability of a filesystem consistency tool to do anything about.

Comment: You can usually edit your original post to include new information. This time I added it for you, but consider creating or linking an account so that you can edit it yourself.

Comment: I suggest replacing "pre-boot scan" with "harddrive self diagnostic during POST". That is likely more correct. Also the message is about the physical HDD having a problem, not the installation on it. You probably need to replace the disk, reinstall windows and restore all important data from your backups. - If this is unclear then consider the HDD as a book. The book is town and falling apart. FSCK and chckdisk are used to correct spelling errors on pages, not to repair the book itself.

Comment: And **DO NOT** try "Install to Hard Drive". This would just destroy your data, if successful, overwriting it with a Linux installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default livecd user account be able to use `sudo` without a password at the terminal prompt. Is this not working for you? (It is definitely the case with the current F19 release, and I think also true for F17.) Alternately, from that account you can  `su -` to  get a root prompt without a password.

You shouldn't need to get into rescue mode or run the installer to do this.

Comment: But does the Fedora Live CD understand and automount NTFS partitions?

Comment: @MichaelHampton If the filesystem is damaged and you want to run `fsck`, you don't want to mount it anyway. The `ntfsprogs` package, which contains `fsck.ntfs`, is part of the default install and included on the livecd. But see my [comment to the question](http://superuser.com/questions/626367/fix-hard-disk-errors-using-fedora-live-cd/626369?noredirect=1#comment779970_626367) about how much use that might actually be.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Linux Install CD and select rescue mode.  In rescue mode, there is either a blank or NO root password and you get dropped into a root shell.  From there you can run fsck.

Comment: Now i am in live mode.And there is an option available for me like "install to Hard Drive".
Can i use that option to get in to the rescue mode.
I am completely new to this linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that your hard drive is physically failing, your initial focus should be on getting data off it. Once the data is safely on trusted media, you can work more on possibly repairing a corrupted file system from there.

[ddrescue](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue) is designed for this task. It has a `--max-retries` option that avoids having the hard drive try too many times to read a bad sector, which might only make it worse. A more Windows-oriented guide to using ddrescue is [here](http://keystoneisit.blogspot.com/2011/08/clone-failing-windows-hard-disk-with.html).

`ddrescue` appears on a few Linux live Cds. I use [CDLinux](http://www.cdlinux.info/wiki/doku.php/).